# Set location to be same as path

Tags: vimrc, python

I keep a vimrc file stored on Dropbox and use symlinks to point to this so my vimrc is always synced up. Recently I got a new laptop and the location of some utilities are different from that of my old machines -- in particular, my Python installation is in a different spot. Is there a way to do "let &pythonthreedll=PATH" where PATH is the location of Python on my local system (regardless of which machine I'm on)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you need to have the environment variable PythonThreeDll defined? Do you know.ow why, for which plugin, for which usage?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt [`'pythonthreedll'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27pythonthreedll%27) is a Vim option [used to specify the location of the Python 3 DLL](https://vimhelp.org/if_pyth.txt.html#python-dynamic) if it's not on your search path (Windows) or if it doesn't match the environment variables used when compiling Vim (Unix)

Comment: My recommendation would be to configure your OS/environment such that Vim doesn't need to be told where `pythonthreedll` is… also note that you can use things like `exepath()`/`executable()` to find executables (not the same as a DLL, obviously, but can help with portability when needed).

Answer (score 1):

I set environment variables on my machine for the Python .dll and the Python directory. Then, I can reference these variables using the $path convention. Not sure if this is the best way to do this however!

Comment: I'm not sue I understand your answer. Maybe sharing some  code would help understanding what you did exactly.